# Devise doing redirect with Angular.js 1.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I made a project with angular 1.0.8 and devise last version, on Rails 4, all worked great, devise was sending respond 401 when I did request to the api without been logged in.
the interceptor was getting the 401 and handle it the way I wanted. 
but then decide to make the upgrade to the last stable version 1.2.1 and all worked great (only needed to change the interceptor, instead of return a function, returned an object), but for some reason devise now does a redirect to the sign_up page instead of send the 401 respond, not sure whats going on because I test with a controller responding with a status: :unauthorized, and my interceptor did caugth it just fine. someone already had this problem when migrating to 1.2.1? as I said the only code I change was the interceptor it self (it works fine with my 401 responds).
all I get is a 302 Found status code.

the interceptor code:

```
.config(function($httpProvider){

var interceptor = function($q, $location, $rootScope) {
return {
  'responseError': function(rejection) {
    if (rejection.status == 401) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('event:unauthorized');
      console.log('got you trying to do something illegal...')
      return rejection;
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection);        
  }
};
 };
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
})
```

**UPDATE**

So after a while trying I realize to get a 401 using angularjs 1.2.1 and Devise I need to:

Add the .json format to all the services url(that needed authentication, eg: `api/events/:id.json`).

Make sure the `config.navigational_formats = []` on `config/initilizers/devise.rb` didn't had the `:json` in its array.

And make sure the `config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true` was set to `true`.

**But I still have the question, why on Angular.js 1.0.8 this worked even with `navigational_formats` array having the `:json` and services dont having `.json`?**

**Its the way its now the right way?**